# How to make url like '/category/category_name/product_name' on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Most web applications got urls like this. `/catalog/category_name/category_id/product_name/product_id`

How to make the same on AngularJS using ui-route? I mean I can do something like /category/products, but how to make the other part I have no idea:(

Answer (score 1):

```
$stateProvider
        .state('catalog', {
            url: '/catalog'
        })
       .state('catalog.categoryName', {
            url: '/catalog/:category_name/:category_id/:product_name/:product_id'
        });
```

and the access in HTML

```
<a href="" ui-sref="app.catalog.name(category_name:yourcategori, category_id: yourcategoryid, product_name:yourproductname, product_id: yourproductid)";
```

or in the controller

```
 $state.go('app.catalog.name',{category_name:yourcategori, category_id: yourcategoryid, product_name:yourproductname, product_id: yourproductid});
```

all these are in the documentation of  [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui)